# How do we release a patch to a prior version of our code on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, versioning, release, patch

So here is an example from someone else's Repo that raises the question nicely.

https://github.com/cfry/dde/releases

Development on this program is progressing well, new releases being put out. A major change from 1.x to 2.x breaks some functionality that a few users depend upon. They are stuck at version [1.1.9](https://github.com/kent/dde/releases/tag/v1.1.9). (1.1.10 actually also breaks their functionality in a small way). But they have found a bug in 1.1.9 that causes intermittent issues.

How can we fix the bug in 1.1.9 and release something publicly that isn't confusing or stupid. What version should it be? 1.1.9.1? 1.1.9A? Still 1.1.9 but with a different date?

We assume it should be a branch of 1.1.9, but we are confused as to how to actually do the release.

I've read this:
[Git strategy to backport bugfixes into older branches (cherry-pick vs. merge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275223/git-strategy-to-backport-bugfixes-into-older-branches-cherry-pick-vs-merge)

And honestly I'm more confused that I was. I think there are issues in that question which do not apply to our needs and which simply overcomplicate the issue.

More than the direct question, where does one go to read about these more advanced GitHub use issues? It certainly doesn't seem to be convered at:

https://help.github.com/

Comment: You really haven't asked a question, other than *what should I name it*, which would be entirely up to you. Asking where to go for reading material is off-topic here (it's a request for us to find or recommend an off-site resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name does not matter that much: what matters is that your program is able somehow to display the exact commit from which it was built, which in turn allows you to find the exact sources.
In term of naming convention, see for instance [semver.org](http://semver.org/) and add a build metadata after 1.1.9.

You need to make a branch to record the fix, and you need to determine if that fix must be also applied ([`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)) to your current development branch, or if it is entirely specific to that version.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, in nice easy steps:
1. Check out the 1.1.9 branch.
2. Fix the bug
3. Commit with a version like 1.1.9-patch1

Comment: @JamesNewton Yes: that way, you can easily see what that version represents.